# How do you compare two arrays that both have multiple properties and objects in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, properties, compare

I am looking for a way to go through each array in a collection. So I have two csvs that I have imported and I need to compare the data on each.

Sample Array contents From CSV1 (Array is $Collection1):

```
Name: Keyboard
Type: InputDevice
ConnectionType: USB

Name: Mouse
Type: InputDevice
ConnectionType: USB
```

Sample Array Contents from CSV2 (Array is $Collection2):

```
Name: Keyboard
Type: InputDevice
ConnectionType: Wireless

Name: Mouse
Type: InputDevice
ConnectionType: Wireless

Name: Monitor
Type: Display
ConnectionType: HDMI
```

So in this case, I would want to have it tell me that Mouse is different and Keyboard is different and there is a new device added. If a device is removed, I'd like to know this too. Is there a way to compare the CSV data? I have tried Compare-Object on the two arrays as a whole

Example:

```
Compare-Object $Collection1 $Collection2
```

But this yields only the new data. And if I remove a block (like Keyboard) and replace it with something else, it sees the same count and so there are no differences. It also doesn't see changes to any of the objects of the properties.

If its a forEach loop I need to use, how do I select the same block (like keyboard) to compare the items, then move onto the next. That doesn't make sense to use a ForEach. sort of confusing.

Comment: You could try `Compare-Object $Collection1 $Collection2 -Property Name,Type,ConnectionType`. Then use `SideIndicator` to show which collection has the difference. You will have to define more criteria for better results. You say you want to see differences, but what does that mean? Is that a line-by-line difference? Is that you expect `Name` and `Type` to be the same across two arrays but `ConnectionType` could be different? There are a lot of combinations that could be engineered here, and I'm sure it would be overkill for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I didn't know you could use "Property after a compare. I can certainly play with this as a potential answer. 
To answer your questions, I am automating our inventory in a SQL table. I am looking for a way to have any day-by-day change updated with this. I want to know if there are ANY changes to anything in the table. If there are I will run a sql update with automation.

Comment: Hmm. I have changed one column on one item. It tells me there is a change, but because I selected one Property it doesn't tell me where the change is.

`
ConnectionType  SlideIndicator
_____________  ___________
Wireless               =>
USB                     <=
`

But when you have many arrays, this cannot be practical to guess where the difference is. Maybe I'm just not thinking outside the box?